# When requesting a quote through 0x API's /swap/v1/quote endpoint, what do I use to batch fill multiple quotes?

Tags: 0x

I see a function in v3 for limit orders called batchFillOrKill but how do achieve this using the quote endpoint? Is there a function I am just not finding or would I have to code my own logic in my smart contract?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

V4 does have a batch fill function for (v4) limit orders but there is no equivalent batch fill function for 0x API quotes (which are not just limit orders).